# Invalid parameter elasticsearch_package_name on Elasticsearch_plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, centos, puppet, elasticsearch-plugin

- OS : 'CentOS 6.5
  '
- ElasticSearch version : '2.3.0'
- Master's puppet version: '3.8.7'
- Client's puppet version : '3.7.4'
- Base module version before upgrade : '0.10.2'
- Base module version after upgrade : '5.1.0'

> Error: could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on
>   SERVER: invalid parameter elasticsearch_package_name on
>   Elasticsearch_plugin[license] at
>   /etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/elasticsearch/manifests/plugin.pp:169
>   on node bla-test01.dom'

Hi,

This error started after we upgraded our Elasticsearch's base (Official from puppet forge) module from version '0.10.2' to '5.1.0'. Our puppet module of elasticsearch worked just fine before the upgrade.

Since the upgrade this error occurred whenever puppet ran on our nodes.

After we saw [this](https://github.com/elastic/puppet-elasticsearch/issues/610) case we tried to restart our puppetserver service. Since the restart, the error occurs once every 3-4 runs of puppet and we have no idea why.

Comment: Could you paste what ```/etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/elasticsearch/manifests/plugin.pp:169 ``` on line 169 of that puppet file has?

Comment: which forge module are you using as there are many on forge and the most populer one is at version 6.4.0.  I will say that your puppet version is no longer supported by puppet-labs and as such support may have been dropped from the foge module you are using.  Finally going from 0.* to 5.* is a big jump, im sussing you did read the change loig?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [elastic/elasticsearch](https://github.com/elastic/puppet-elasticsearch) module which is the one you seem to be using i can see that the elastic_plugin custom type did not have the [elasticsearch_package_name](https://github.com/elastic/puppet-elasticsearch/blob/0.10.2/lib/puppet/type/elasticsearch_plugin.rb) parameter in version 0.11.0 however the [5.1.0 version does](https://github.com/elastic/puppet-elasticsearch/blob/5.1.0/lib/puppet/type/elasticsearch_plugin.rb#L14-L16).  This looks to me that you may have updated the module on the system but have not restarted the puppet server so it still has the 0.11.0 custom type/provider ruby files loaded.

Restart the puppet master server and see if that fixes the issue